# is there a way to remove rtf from a database memo field within a formula in crystal reports version 11.5.10

Tags: crystal-reports, rtf

I have a database memo field stored as rich text format ( rtf). I can drop it in a report and set the format of the field as rtf within crystal reports version 11.5.10 and see the text without the rtf control characters. However, I want to construct a crystal reports formula/function to process the ascii text, so is there a way to programmatically within crystal report to strip the rtf control characters from the memo field so I can work with only the ascii characters ?

I could not find such a function within CR or mention of a solution to this problem by googling.

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

You could try looking at this.
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/BillQuick/message/937?

I found it and used it to change/override RTF font settings to print large text for easier reading.  It could probably be modified to strip to ASCII.

Cheers,

Comment: Can you please summarize the contents of the link for completeness?

Comment: Link provided requires registration to view content. Bad idea.